# Create loading spinner angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have to create loading spinner when my data is waiting to complete.

my service:

```
...
  constructor(private _http:Http) {

  }
  getDataFromApi() {
    return this._http.get('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

my component:

```
...
export class MainListComponent implements OnInit {
  getData:Array<Beer>;
  constructor(private _apiDataService:ApiDataService) {}

   onTestGet() {
    this._apiDataService.getDataFromApi().subscribe( 
      res => {
        this.getData = res;  
      }
     );
   }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.onTestGet();
  }
}
```

I found a spinner on npm but I don't know how to use it. I have to disable webpage while something is loading.

Comment: Please refer this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-block-ui

Answer (score 1):

Before Calling the service set loading spinner on a show method and after getting response set that stuff on a hidden method.

Likewise, you can see it over here.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-loading-spinner

Comment: i used ng4-loading-spinner and i have used `spinner.hide()` inside of my `.subscribe()` and my spinner is hide before loading

Comment: ok, it works, but i find a problem. The problem is that i want to hide spinner after render all html tags on my website.

Comment: can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Font Awesome - Animated Icons:  http://fontawesome.io/examples/
and display it before calling the service and hide after you got response

```
 _isLoading: boolean;
....
  this._isLoading = true;

  this.myService.get("/api/...")
            .subscribe(res => {
                     .....
                      this._isLoading = false;
            }
        );
```

in template:

```
 <i *ngIf="_isLoading" 
     class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"
     style="margin: auto;display:block;"></i>
```